# no new line feature in text_area?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've created an email feature in my application.  It all works well except the `text_area` does not seem to support new lines.  As I add my text and hit the return key, the delivered email will contain only white spaces and no new lines.  This is my index code:

```
  <h1>Send email to all users</h1>

<br />

  <%= form_tag :action => 'sendmail' %>

  <p><label for="email_subject">Subject</label>
  <%= text_field 'email', 'subject' %></p>

  <br />

  <label for="email_message">Message</label>

  <br />
  <%= text_area(:email, :message, :cols => 20, :rows => 40) %>


   <br />
   <br />

  <%= submit_tag "Send" %>

  <%= form_tag %>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Mark

This is my controller:

```
class MailMessageController < ApplicationController

  def sendmail
     email = params["email"]
      recipient = email["user"]
      subject = email["subject"]
      message = email["message"]
     MailMessage.deliver_contact(recipient, subject, message)
     return if request.xhr?
     render :file => 'mail_message/msg.dryml'
  end

  def index
    render :file => 'mail_message/index.html'
  end
```

end

This is my contact.erb file in my views:

```
<%= @message %>

<%= "\n" %>

-------

<%= "\n" %>

Please do not reply to this email.
```

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you cannot find a bug, the problem is usually that you are looking in the wrong place.  I think that may be the issue here and that newlines are not showing up because of problems with your mail template, and is nothing to do with the form you showed us here ...

could you post the template you are using to display the mail?

```
<pre><%= @message %></pre>
```

may be what you are looking for ...

Answer (score 2):

Emails use views like all standard pages.

I think you just missed to use simple_format to render the \n.

See doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format